# Using Multiple Modules which have Same binding to different types

Tags: guice, guice-3

I have two different Modules which have different bindings to same interface and multiple sub modules. Example below

```
public PublisherModule { 
     public void configure() {
         bind(ITransport.class).to(TCPTransport.class)
         install(new ServerModule()) //Has Binding EndPoint.class to ServerEndPoint.class
     }
}

public SubscriberModule { 
     public void configure() {
         bind(ITransport.class).to(HttpTransport.class)
         install(new ClientModule()) //Has binding EndPoint.class to ClientEndPoint.class
     }
}
```

Now I came across a use case where the two modules need to be used together.Any solution?

PS: I cannot use any Named Bindings for now. I was looking for solution like(which doesn't work)

```
public void configure() {
Injector injPublisher = Guice.createInjector(new PublisherModule());
Publisher pub = injPublisher.createInjector(Publisher.class)

bind(Publisher.class).toInstance(pub)
install(new SubscriberModule());
}
```

is there any work around?

Comment: Can you edit the Modules you list? If so, you may want to consider [PrivateModule](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html) so you only expose `Publisher.class` and `Subscriber.class` respectively.

Comment: Thanks, that is a considerable alternative.  But we have too many modules and interfaces..Have to refactor a lot..

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Jeff Bowman, I have access to Modules, I can edit it to make Modules private.

PS: Actually the above piece of configure method code is working. The 
Instances that are created lazily(e.g ITransport reference in publisher is created via @assisted inject factory, which is also instantiated lazily based on some client action) use binding of Publisher Module. Whereas instances created early are from Subscriber Module. Not sure how to understand this behavior